# How to print all the names of locations in realtime database of firebase in react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

The aim is to print all the location names like an array from the database.

Ive tried the following:

```
export default class MTwo extends Component {
constructor(){

    super()
    this.state ={
      done:'',
      bloodConnect:'',
    }

    }

    componentWillMount=()=> {
    const oneroot = firebase.database().ref('logtestishaan');


    oneroot.child('machine_1').on('value', snap=>{
      this.setState({
        bloodConnect: snap.val(),

      });
  });
```

Comment: Did you try logging bloodConnect on console?

Comment: yes i did. And I am getting values in the console. I just want to know how to print them out